# Can we automate the process of github repository creation, commit, raising a pull request? (preferably with node js)

Tags: node.js, github, automation, commit, pull-request

I have tried with bash script (involving node js) and also using postman as well, but I want to automate all these processes in a way such that, we just have to select the options as to create/ commit/ pull request and just enter the details.
We can say as a user want to do something with the repo, it should be easier for him if we automate the repository and its processes...

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub API and any UI design framework like Electron.js or something. Build the UI and add the required buttons and the API call for each button.